# Reading File into Vector Delimited by Comma and New Line

Tags: c++, file, vector, delimiter

Say that I want to read in a .txt file and is formatted in such a way

```
Max,1979
Wade,1935
Hugh,1983
Eric,1936
```

Here is the code I am using to

1. Read in the file.
2. Store it into a vector of string and int (For names and years respectively)

   ```
   void calcAges(){
   while (getline(infile, line, ',')){
       names.push_back(line);
       years.push_back(line);
   }
   }

   void printNames(){
   cout << "\n\tDisplaying data...\n";

       for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
           cout << (i + 1) << ".\tName: " << names[i] << "\tYear: " << years[i] << endl;
       }
   }
   ```

Output should look like:

```
1.    Name: Max    Year: 1979
.
.
.
and so on...
```

However, I'm having trouble trying to make it so the file I read into my "infile" split at both a comma and a new line. I am storing these variables into a vector array so I can sort and switch later on. I am stumped at this point.

Comment: just put another `getline(infile,line)` (no delim this time) before appending to `years`. this will then read the rest of the line

Comment: Can't believe I think even think of this! However, when I tried putting in a second "getline(infile,line)", I get an error saying that getline can't take in an int?

Beside that, changing my years vector to a string makes the code all right. But it doesn't make sense to store a string vector of years. Thank you so much though!

Comment: you have to explictly convert line to an int when you push into `years`

Answer (score 0):

The new line is considered as a normal character once you have given ',' as delimiter. So use `getline()` without specifying a delimiter (default is new line) and try to extract the name and year from the string you have obtained. It can be done pretty easily using `find_first_of()` and `substr()`

Example:

```
while(getline(infile,str))
{
     int index = str.find_first_of(',');
     string name = str.substr(0,index);
     string date = str.substr(index+1);
      // Do something with name and date

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! However I'm trying to understand the second part of the substring. When you say (index + 1), are you saying 'after the comma and anything after that'? Also does it stop reading after seeing a new line in the text file ('\n')?

Comment: The "str" only contains one line at a time. So the second line reads until the end of that line. And YES,  anything after comma is put into second string.

Comment: I see, thank you. This was very helpful for me. So if the text file line were for example 
    Max, 1979
The name with a comma and a space, would I write:
     string date = str.substr(index+2);?

Answer (score 0):

A [StringStream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is much more powerful when it comes to these kind of operations. However, in your case (which is considered rather simple) you can get away with simple operations on strings.
I would suggest reading each line into your temp string then split it on the comma and add the values into your vectors, something like the following:

```
void calcAges(){
    while (getline(infile, line)){  // Read a whole line (until it reads a '\n', by default)
        names.push_back(line.substr(0,line.find(",")); // Read from the beginning of the string to the comma, then push it into the vector
        years.push_back(std::stoi(line.substr(line.find(",") + 1)); // Read from the comma to the end of the string, parse it into an integer, then push it into the vector
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that you're using `std::string` from the `<string>` library as the type for your `line` variable.

I didn't compile and test this by the way, so I'm not sure it would work as is, but I wrote it just to give you an idea about the logical approach

Cheers

Comment: This worked, so I guess one of the most optimal ways of reading in files is to go line by line, and then work from that line? I can see what you mean by getting away with simple operations on my code. Thank you though!

Comment: It really depends on the case, but generally you'll be reading files from disk, which means that the reading operation is much slower than the rest of your code. So it's a code optimization practice to do your file access operations in batches just to make things as smooth as possible. Of course I'm talking about optimizations that won't even be noticed unless you're operating on huge amounts of data, but I guess a good practice is always good.